# G edit - Find tag in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gedit

in Gedit Can I use  image tag for find and  replace with a space.
I simply need to remove entire image tags in the html Using Find & Replace

Comment: THis would be better suited on Superuser.

Comment: For one, this *should* be on Stack Overflow. The part about how to open search and replace is for SU, but the part about how to create a regex to replace image tags should be on SO. (where it will ultimately be shunned for trying to use regex to parse HTML)

Answer (score 1):

You will need the "Regex Search & Replace" to do this. Here's how to install the plugin:

- Download: http://vaem.googlecode.com/files/gedit2_regex_replace_plugin.tar.gz
- Open Nautilus and go to this directory: `~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins` (create all of them if necessary)
- Extract the contents of `gedit2_regex_replace_plugin.tar.gz` in `~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins` (make sure that at the end you will have a directory named `regex_replace` and a file named `regex_replace.gedit-plugin` inside `~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins`)
- Now enable the plugin: Edit -> Preferences -> Plugins tab and check "Regex Search & Replace"
- Click the Close button
- Now let's use this plugin: press `Control + Alt + H`
- In "*Search for*" write the following regexp: `<img(.*)(/>|></img>)`

  - (This should be enough to catch both "new" and "old" style img tags)
- The plugin won't let your replace with an empty string so either push "Find" and manually delete all occurrences or insert a blank space and click "Replace all"

  - (Anyway I suggest to use "Find and Replace" so that you have a chance to review what is going to be removed).